# how to update mongodb nested element

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a database of characters, this is character schema:

```
const charactersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 30,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  items: [{
    name: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 30,
      required: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      required: true
    },
  }],
});
```

I was able to do some of the actions (get all character, get one character and delete).
I want to do a function where i increment items quantity by some number and if this item is not exist, create it. and do the oposite - decrement item quantity.

i read all the mongodb documentation about it but it's not working..

can someone help me with that?

Comment: If you want to increment values, you can use the [$inc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator, this can also be used to decrement values by passing in a negative number (see the documentation).

Comment: I don't really understand the point of decrementing item quantity if the item doesn't exist. Your schema says it would just have a default value of 1. Should this default value then be 0?